# Typesafe Javascript

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction, interface, type-safety

Is there a way to enforce types in JavaScript? I'm thinking of a pre-processor which takes an input file written in ActionScript 3 or Java and converts it to JS.

I do not need a big run-time apparatus, I just need to introduce the idea of compile-time in my workflow and run the trivial compile-time checks on my code (and also use interfaces). Neither I need the API from Java or Flex, just the syntax.

The standard browser-functions could also be checked against the IDL definitions, but it is not a must.

Comment: By types you mean variable types? because that's easily done with `typeof(variable)`.

Comment: You can enforce 'typesafe equality checking' with `===` and `!==`.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, I know it is possible to check types in JS **manually**, I just don't want to do it.

Comment: For compile-time type validation the JavaScript needs to be generated (as JavaScript only allows you to do runtime checks). This is likely to become the norm for big JavaScript projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should take a look at the [haxe project](http://haxe.org/doc/intro).

Haxe is a very nice typed language that uses type inference (i.e. you're not forced to write a lot of type declarations) but that enforces type correctness at compile time.

The language has a javascript-like syntax and the compiler can generate code for the neko virtual machine, for javascript, as3, c++ or PHP.

## Update

Today the most popular choice is probably [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), a superset of Javascript that allows optional type declarations that are enforced compile time.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I dreamed about :)

Answer (score 12):

Whilst I'm a little late to this party, I think it's definitely worth mentioning [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/)  (which is a Google product) and [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) (which is a Microsoft product).

JavaScript is fast becoming an extremely popular language as applications become more web based. However as you have pointed out, JavaScript lacks type safety, and to name a few other things; classes, interfaces and packages/namespaces/modules.

This is where Dart and TypeScript step in. These languages are essentially supersets of JavaScript. When you write Dart or TypeScript code, it is compiled into clean, standards compliant JavaScript.

The benefits of Dart and TypeScript are that they provide type safety, interfaces, classes etc. Thus allowing you to write cleaner, scalable, manageable applications, which still run in the browser.

Being a Microsoft oriented programmer, I've had a lot of experience with TypeScript, including being somewhat active in the development of the language (you can find information for TypeScript development at [codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/))

My only concern at the moment is that TypeScript is lacking in some fundamental features. It seems that some of the current implementation (0.9.0 alpha) has some equally gaping holes that might deter the savvy developer from using it at the moment (subject to change of course).

I cannot really comment on Dart, as I have only used this a few times, but my overall experience with Dart was good!

Answer (score 4):

[GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) does what looking for, but its a way oversized for the most cases. You could take a look at googles [closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library/) framework which fakes the typed safe with [anotations](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html)

Comment: Thanks, closure is definitely a step into the right direction, but being a JS2JS compiler it forces me to use those uber-clumsy annotations. I admit this is useful if JS is the only laguage one knows, but IMHO using Java or AS3 would be the *right way*.

Answer (score 4):

There are many **statically-typed** languages that are designed with the **specific goal** of compiling down to JavaScript (the so-called *assembly* of the web):

- [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) by Facebook
- [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) by Google
- [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) by Microsoft
- [JXS](http://jsx.github.io/) by DeNA

Answer (score 3):

While `typeof` will return `'object'` for every object or array, you can use the `instanceof` statement. Say you have a class `Person`, and want to see whether the object passed to your function is a `Person`, you can do this:

```
function someFunc(person){
  if(! person instanceof Person)
    throw('argument needs to be an instance of Person.');

  /* ... do your stuff ... */
}
```

If you just want to make sure a variable is the number 3 instead of a string '3', you only need to use `===` instead of `==`:

```
if( var === 3 ){
  /* ... do your stuff ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the point of the question is that I want these things automated. Using `===` is not a big overhead, but run-time checks are only useful coupled with unit testing and even then it is not guaranteed that every call of the function has been run during the tests.

Answer (score 2):

I agreed that Javascript is a beautiful language, with some glaring holes, the worst and most unremarked of which is the absence of static type-safety.

As eskimoblood pointed out, there are some half-measures in the form of GWT and Closure but the *right* answer, imo, is Scala, which combines Javascript's flexibility and expressive power with a type system much better than Java's -- or that *would* be the right answer except that the Scala-GWT project seems to have gotten bogged down.

For now, we wait...

Answer (score 0):

[Infernu](https://github.com/sinelaw/infernu/blob/master/README.md) is a type-safe subset of JavaScript. It doesn't compile into JavaScript - it can run as-is in your browser! The type checker supports full type inference, so no type annotations are needed (in the future they will be supported for documentation and for deliberate distinction between structurally identical types). It isn't ready yet for usage, but a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a lightweight typesafe function wrapper for nodejs/browser:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeshave

Its 3.9K gzipped, supports jsonschema, and works pretty much everywhere. So:

```
foo = function(bar){

}
```

could be rewritten like so:

```
foo = typesafe({ 
  bar: { type: "object" } 
}, function(bar){

}
```

Or just wrapped later on, including validating deepnested structures, and optional args:

```
foo = typesafe({
  bar: { 
    type: "object", 
    required: true,
    properties: {
      foo: { type: "string", required:true },
      items: [{
        type: "integer"  
      }]
    }
  }
}, foo ); 

foo({ foo: "helloworld", items:[1,2,3] });
```

It looks less noisy in coffeescript imho