# Parameter-checking library

Tags: javascript, validation, testing, verification

I don't know what's it called, but I'm looking for lightweight JS libraries with which I can properly test passing parameters (at least general type-checking and integer detection).

I've seen UnderscoreJS, but it doesn't have everything I need + it has some other stuff that I won't use ("bloat" for my use-case).

SIDENOTE: I'm really into frantically validating & verifying my input parameters for as long as I can remember...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050507/typesafe-javascript

Comment: Haxe, GWT, Dart and TypeScript seem cool and I should definitely keep an eye on them, but I'm looking for something more pure JS. For now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Google Closure's [type annotations](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#types) for a flexible solution.

Also see some other suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050507/typesafe-javascript)